# Add char in between string

Tags: dart, flutter

I want a function which takes string as an argument and add any char between string after every 3 letters.

**For example:**

```dart
func("11111111"){}
```

**will return:**

`11,111,111`

Comment: I've updated answer, please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

String convertFun(String src, String divider) {
  String newStr = '';
  int step = 3;
  for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i += step) {
    newStr += src.substring(i, math.min(i + step, src.length));
    if (i + step < src.length) newStr += divider;
  }
  return newStr;
}
```

**UPD:**
(for separating symbols from end, not from beginning)

```
String convertFun(String src, String divider) {
  String newStr = '';
  int step = 3;
  for (int i = src.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= step) {
    String subString ='';
    if (i > 3) {
      subString += divider;
    }
    subString += src.substring( i < step ? 0 : i - step, i);
    newStr = subString + newStr;
  }
  return newStr;
}
```

Comment: the output of 1111111 must be 1,111,111 not 111,111,1 it must start placing "," from back.

Answer (score 1):

```
String func(String str){    
    RegExp exp = RegExp(r".{1,3}");
    Iterable<Match> matches = exp.allMatches(str);

    List<dynamic> list = [];
    matches.forEach((m)=>list.add(m.group(0)));

    return list.join(',');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  String myFunction(String str, String separator) {
    String tempString = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if(i % 3 == 0 && i > 0) {
        tempString = tempString + separator;
      }
      tempString = tempString + str[i];
    }
    return tempString;
  }
```

And use it for example, like this:

```
Text(myFunction("111111111", ","))
```

Comment: Sorry, but i forgot to mention that it must start parsing from backwards like in dollar.     For example "11111"=>"111,11"not"11,111" .

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions work for your stated problem, but if you are looking to add commas in numbers (as in your example), you'll want to add the comma's from the right to the left instead.
ie:  12345678 you would want 12,345,678 not 123,456,78

```
String convertFun(String src, String divider) {
    StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder();
    int step = 3;
    for (int i = src.length(); i > 0; i -= step) {
        newStr.insert(0, src.substring( i < step ? 0 : i - step, i));
        if (i > 3) {
            newStr.insert(0, divider);
        }
    }
    return newStr.toString();
}
```